# System Images with different Model Identifiers

Tags: macos, backup, disk-utility, restore, mac-pro

I have been tasked with creating a default system image to use to both back up and use to deploy to new systems.

After checking the stats on the 7 systems in question I've found that there are multiple model identifiers.

Would I be correct in my assumption that a system image made for one model identifier would not be useful for a system with a different identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, one image should work for all models of Mac that are compatible with that particular version of Mac OS X. A single image can be used across all kinds of Macs: MacBooks, iMacs, Mac minis, Mac Pros.

So check each of your 7 Macs and identify the most recent version of Mac OS X that each Mac can run.

Comment: So as long as they can handle the OS version the image was made with, we're ok?

Comment: Yes, that is how it has always worked. Oh, and of course you should also take the size of the image and the hard drive capacity of each Mac into consideration.